# asp.net wizard control, set step name unvisible

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't want to show stepname. "Next" and "finish button" is enough for me. How to unvisible these?![image]

Second question's; after FinishButton's click, I want to redirect first step automatically. How to do?

```
 <asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="MyWizard" OnNextButtonClick="MyWizard_NextButtonClick"
                Width="440px" Height="200px" OnFinishButtonClick="MyWizard_FinishButtonClick">
                <WizardSteps>
                    <asp:WizardStep ID="Wizardstep1" runat="server" StepType="auto">
                   </asp:WizardStep>
                    <asp:WizardStep ID="Wizardstep2" runat="server" StepType="auto">
        </asp:WizardStep>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom LayoutTemplate within `Wizard` control to hide step names. For example:

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="headerPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="navigationPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
```

Remeber that placeholders' id names matter. Placeholer responsible for displaying list of steps that you circled has id `sideBarPlaceHolder` (and you should not have any placeholder with this id inside `LayoutTemlpate`)

Second question:
You can have custom navigation template, for example:

```
<FinishNavigationTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="PreviousButton" runat="server" Text="Previous step" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MovePrevious" />
    <asp:Button ID="FinishButton" runat="server" Text="Finish" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="MoveComplete" OnCLick="FinishButton_Click" />
</FinishNavigationTemplate>
```

Note that these buttons have fixed `CommandName` (`Wizard` control expects this). You can try to use finish button's `OnClick` event to jump to the first step:

```
protected void FinishButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 0;
}
```